# Get value from an input

Tags: python, django

How i get the value `Flu` with input name `gejala_id0` in django from my input like this :

```
<form method="POST" action="/diagnosis/response/" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="AVAST_PAM_nonloginform">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="B09UeUu83ADaQQkFe2GpIV5TyO5ruEZNA1zwJJ7zgMxCRR7I0Ing4Y7wQRR22NQj">
            <ul id="id_gejala_id0">
                <li>
                    <label for="id_gejala_id0_0">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="gejala_id0" value="Flu" id="id_gejala_id0_0">
                        Flu
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
request.POST.getlist('gejala_id0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
request.POST.get('gejala_id0')
```

Comment: It's return `None`

Comment: Did you select any option in the checkbox?